# MVC4 Validate Item Selected In DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page to create `objects`, and in this I have a `DropDownList`.  If I select an item from the list my page will save correctly, however if I don't select an item it looks like it fails on a postback as the objects will be null.

What I want is to try and validate whether the user has selected an item (default is "Please Select...").

I have code that will check and see in the controller if the item is null, but it's how do I then display a message?  Keeping all other details if they exist.

```
public ActionResult Create(int objectId = 0)
{
var resultModel = new MyObjectModel();
resultModel.AllObjects = new SelectList(_system.GetAllObjects(objectId)); 
// GetAllObjects juts returns a list of items for the drop down.
return View(resultModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int? objectId, FormCollection collection)
{
try
{
int objectIdNotNull = 0;
if (objectId > 1)
{
objectIdNotNull = (int) objectId;
}
string objectName = collection["Name"];
int objectTypeSelectedResult = 1;
int.TryParse(collection["dllList"], out objectTypeSelectedResult);
if (!Convert.ToBoolean(objectTypeSelectedResult))
{
// So here I have discovered nothing has been selected, and I want to alert the user
    return RedirectToAction("Create",
        new {ObjectId = objectIdNotNull, error = "Please select an Object Type"});
}
....

return RedirectToAction(...)

}
catch
{
return View();
}
}
```

The above code just goes to the Create page but doesn't display an error.  In my View for Create I have the following line which I assumed would display any errors:
     @ViewData["error"]

*Additional code*
Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
public class MyObjectModel
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Object Type")]
public SelectList AllObjects { get; set; }  // I populate the drop down with this list
}
}
```

View:

```
@model MyNameSpace.MyObjectModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create </h2>

<p class="text-error">@ViewData["Message"]</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>       
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyObject.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.MyObjectType.Name, new {style="width: 750px"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyObjectType.Name)
</div>

<div>
<label for="ddlList">Choose Type</label>
@if (@Model != null)
{  
@Html.DropDownList("ddlList", Model.AllObjects, "Please Select...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllObjects, "An object must be selected", new { @class = "redText"})
}
</div>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: You still need help? let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are validating the `SelectList` which is wrong

<strike>[Required(ErrorMessage = "An object must be selected")] 

    public SelectList AllObjects { get; set; }</strike>

Your Model should be

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Object Type")]
public int ObjectId { get; set; }
public string ObjectName { get; set; }
```

Your Controller(no need for form collection thats the whole point of MVC)

```
public ActionResult Create(int Id = 0)
{
    MyObjectModel resultModel = new MyObjectModel();

    var ObjectResultList = _system.GetAllObjects(Id);
    var ObjectSelectList = new SelectList(ObjectResultList, "id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ObjectList = ObjectSelectList;

    return View(resultModel);
}
```

Your Post controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyObjectModel o)
{
    try
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                            //It's valid , your code here!

                return RedirectToAction("ObjectCreated", new { id = o.objectId });
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState
                    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
                    .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
    //If we get here it means the model is not valid, We're in trouble
    //then redisplay the view repopulate the dropdown
    var ObjectResultList = _system.GetAllObjects(objectId);
    var ObjectSelectList = new SelectList(ObjectResultList, "id", "value");
    ViewBag.ObjectList = ObjectSelectList;


    return View(o);
}
```

Your View should be strongly Typed

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ObjectId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ObjectId,
       (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ObjectList, "-- Select One Object --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ObjectId)
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @meda I've tried so my Model looks like this ` @Html.DropDownList("ddlList", Model.AllObjects, "Please Select...") @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllObjects) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllObjects)` however this just outputs False for each item in the list, and that's before I even hit save.

Comment: @MattR it's not `AllObject` you are validating you are selecting only one item so ObjectID

Comment: I'm a little confused (MVC is new to me), if I create this new item in the Model doesn't that mean I have to change my code in my controller too?  As at the minute I just get the selected type from collection[ddlList]

Comment: please add view & model code to your post, we will get this sorted out

Comment: Unfortunately yes I still need help, I hope you had a good weekend.  I have got it to now display False for each item in the list so I'm relatively happy with that.  However it always displays the error when the page is first opened (and I set a default value of "Please Select.."), I want this validation to only take place when I click to Submit the page and to stop it from doing any actions.  I shall update the main question with the view / model shortly.

Comment: Done. Just took me a while to change certain things in it.

Comment: Great , can you also add the Get controller? you only have the POST one here

Comment: I've added it just above the POST.

Comment: @MattR I updated my answer let me know if you have issue, dont forget to accept if it helped you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that still isn't working.  When I altered the it still functions and goes to the POST method, and if "-- Select One Object --" is the selected object then `ModelState.IsValid` is still set to true so it never seems to hit anywhere to display that one needs to be selected.  It doesn't complete the save as a NULL reference exception is thrown (I know why, it's because the Value is empty so it can't parse it to an ID.

Comment: Sorry for the silly long delay.  Whilst I still had issues I was able to use this as a basis to solve my problem

Comment: @MattR thats crazy I dont even remember this post lol, oh well good luck bro!